# CORS error loading 3rd party Google API in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, cors, google

I need some help because I'm encountering a CORS error using the Google API javascript library (taken from https://apis.google.com/js/api.js) running inside Lightning Web Components.

Error message in the browser console:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.FQMyBOWbNKQ.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQ/rs=AGLTcCN26pA1ff1pmP_btrYNbcyVNWJGOQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0' from origin 'https://10724769canadainc-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Some notes:

- I've added a CSP policy to https://apis.google.com
- I downloaded the https://apis.google.com/js/api.js file into a static resource.
- This library is referenced in this sample code from Google:
  https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js#python-3.x

Here's my LWC component that uses platformResourceLoader to load the static resource and call handleClientLoad() which loads client:auth2 which I believe is loading code from a 3rd party source which is what triggers the CORS policy.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import gapiLibrary from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/gapi';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class oauth extends LightningElement {

        renderedCallBackCalled = false;

        renderedCallback() {

            if (this.renderedCallBackCalled) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                this.renderedCallBackCalled = true;
        
                loadScript(this, gapiLibrary)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.handleClientLoad();
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('oauth.renderedCallback: error: ' + error);
                    });

            } catch (error) {
                console.log('oauth.renderedCallback: error: ' + error);
            }
        }

      // On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
      handleClientLoad() {
        try {
            // Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state listeners
            gapi.load('client:auth2', function() {

                // Console Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.FQMyBOWbNKQ.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQ/rs=AGLTcCN26pA1ff1pmP_btrYNbcyVNWJGOQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0' from origin 'https://10724769canadainc-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('oauth.handleClientLoad: error: ' + error);
        }
      }

}
```